# How to map a dictionary with a complex key type (CultureInfo) using FluentNHibernate

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have dictionary which I'm mapping using Fluent NHibernate. The dictionary has a complex key type `CultureInfo`. My database can't store that type so I want to use a string representation of it.

In mappings other than dictionary mappings, I can successfully map `CultureInfo`-properties using a user type convention. Now I wonder how to do it for dicationary mappings.

Here's the entity that contains the dictionary:

```
public class MultilingualPhrase : Entity
{
    private IDictionary<CultureInfo, string> languageValues;

    public virtual IDictionary<CultureInfo, string> LanguageValues
    {
        get
        {
            return languageValues;
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the auto mapping override for the entity:

```
public void Override(AutoMapping<MultilingualPhrase> mapping)
{
    mapping
        .HasMany(n => n.LanguageValues)
        .Access.ReadOnlyPropertyThroughCamelCaseField()
        .AsMap<string>("CultureName")
        .Element("Phrase")
        .Table("MultilingualPhraseValues");
}
```

This mapping (obviously) causes the following error:

> Failed to convert parameter value from a CultureInfo to a String.

I know NHibernate has a type custom type implementation for `CultureInfo` (I'm using it for mapping properties) but how do I specify it in my mapping override?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine with FNH ClassMap (not sure about automapping) in NH 3.1 and FNH 1.2:

```
HasMany(n => n.LanguageValues)
    .Access.ReadOnlyPropertyThroughCamelCaseField()
    .AsMap<CultureInfo>("CultureName")
    .Element("Phrase")
    .Table("MultilingualPhraseValues");
```

Comment: Wonderful, I guess I was too focused on the explicit type on AsMap being the target type instead of the source type. Thanks!