# Map a dictionary with a custom key type using FluentNHibernate

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I need to map a Dictionary<TenthNm,double> in one of my ClassMaps, but the key is custom type (essentially, TenthNm is an object that has only an int property). There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5833175/how-to-map-a-dictionary-with-a-complex-key-type-cultureinfo-using-fluentnhiber), which lead me to this:

```
      HasMany(x => x.ExcitationCurve)
        .Table("PresetCurveExcitation")
        .KeyColumn("PresetCurveId")
        .AsMap<TenthNm>("Wavelength")
        .Element("Value");
```

This works, but the TenthNm object is stored as a BLOB, where it simply could be an int.

In other ClassMaps, with only a single TenthNm property, I use

```
      Map(x => x.Wavelength).CustomType<TenthNmUserType>();
```

with TenthNmUserType being a class implementing IUserType, so it is stored as an int there.

But how can I tell NHibernate to use TenthNmUserType (or a custom int mapping)?

Answer (score 1):

A colleague found the answer: Just use the `AsMap<TenthNmUserType>` instead of `AsMap<TenthNm>`, so it now looks like this:

```
HasMany(x => x.ExcitationCurve)
        .Table("PresetCurveExcitation")
        .KeyColumn("PresetCurveId")
        .AsMap<TenthNmUserType>("Wavelength")
        .Element("Value");
```